# Can we Put 3 database data in One Table

Tags: laravel

I am self learner and stuck at one point. I don't know is that possible or not. Please refer image of data get in array.

I have 3 database table "animalsell", "dairyincomes" and "othersell". I sucessfully able to get required data from this.
Now I want to put the same in one table in blade file (refer table image)

Controller file where i collect the data

```
       $fiveincomedata = Dairyincome::select(
                DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(milksaledate, "%M %Y") as "month_name",SUM(totalamount) as "totalamount", max(milksaledate) as milksaledate')
                )
                ->whereBetween('milksaledate', [Carbon::now()->subMonth(6), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])
                ->groupBy('month_name')
                ->orderBy('milksaledate', 'desc')
                ->get()->toArray();


            // Income from Animal Sell   
            $fiveanimalselldata = Animalsell::select(
                DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(selldate, "%M %Y") as "month_name",SUM(totalamount) as "totalamount", max(selldate) as selldate')
                )
                ->whereBetween('selldate', [Carbon::now()->subMonth(6), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])
                ->groupBy('month_name')
                ->orderBy('selldate', 'desc')
                ->get()->toArray();

            
            // Income from Other Sell   
            $fiveotherselldata = Othersell::select(
                DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(saledate, "%M %Y") as "month_name",SUM(totalamount) as "totalamount", max(saledate) as saledate')
                )
                ->whereBetween('saledate', [Carbon::now()->subMonth(6), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])
                ->groupBy('month_name')
                ->orderBy('saledate', 'desc')
                ->get()->toArray();
```

Blade File

```
      <div class="card-body">

                  <table id="incometable" class="table m-0 table table-bordered table-hover table" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Amount (Milk Sale)</th>
                        <th>Amount (Animal Sale)</th>
                        <th>Amount (Other Sale)</th>
                        <th>Total Amount </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                      @foreach ($fiveincomedata as $fivei )
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{ $fivei->month_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{$fivei->totalamount}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>

                  </table>

                </div>
```

Hope i explain my problem clearly and thanks for help in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge()` function.

For example:

```
$fiveincomedata = Dairyincome::all();
$fiveanimalselldata = Animalsell::all();
$fiveotherselldata = Othersell::all();

$merged = $fiveincomedata->merge($fiveanimalselldata);
$merged = $merged->merge($fiveotherselldata);

$array = $merged->toArray();
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-merge

Comment: It not working for Me.... I tried to use "  $result = array_merge_recursive ($fiveanimalselldata,$fiveotherselldata,$fiveincomedata); "" which give me the required result. But now i can not use $result to show data in blade file table. Error is ---Attempt to read property "month_name" on array .
$result is giving following result
array:3 [▼
  "March 2022" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "12000.00"
    1 => "5000.00"
    2 => "742.90"
  ]
  "February 2022" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "34000.00"
    1 => "21000.00"
    2 => "70.00"
  ]

Comment: You need to use the `merge()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
array_merge($a1,$a2);
```

or
push the data into a common array.